# Given a debian package name, how do I get a URL to the latest .deb URL?

Tags: debian, package-management, deb

Say for example I wish to install the latest Debian package "libgcc1" for Jessie on AMD64.

How can I determine the correct URL to download from https://packages.debian.org

For example, in this case, clicking manually through the https://packages.debian.org website gets me ultimately to the correct download, which is:

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/libgcc1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb

IMPORTANT NOTE:
I do NOT have apt available. I am writing some code that manually extracts the dependency names from .deb packages, but I am now stuck trying to work out the next steps, which is to get the correct actual .deb package for the package name.

So for example I need to go from these bits of information:

- package name: libgcc1
- version: latest
- architecture: amd64
- debian release: jessie

to:

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/libgcc1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb

How can I determine this relationship?

EDIT: for all the people asking "Why not use apt?", the answer is that the core problem I am trying to solve is to install apt. I can't use apt because I am trying to install apt.

thanks

Comment: You can get the latest packages from the [jessie allpackages list](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/allpackages) (HUGE); but you'll still need to resolve everything. Why not use apt?

Comment: Don't forget you really should be considering the security updates, too, which are in a separate repository package list

Comment: Re: your edit: A Debian system without such an essential package as `apt` is very broken. Either (1) fix it by downloading `apt` using `apt` from elsewhere (maybe even using `debootstrap`?), or (2) reinstall, or (3) find and install `apt` by hand with a web browser, then install other packages using `apt`.

Comment: @celada there is a complex recursive dependency requirement to get apt and all its dependencies installed in the correct order. Not something to do by hand. Better to write a program to do it. I want the absolute barest minimum installed ot get apt working thus not interested in debootstrap.

Comment: `debootstrap --variant=minbase` is your best bet then — it only installs essential packages and `apt`. That's the absolute barest minimum you can have with a working `apt` and guaranteed working packages when you *do* install them later (I'm assuming that you want `apt` so you can then install other packages).

Comment: @StephenKitt as far as I can tell debootstrap adds alot of stuff not needed to install a package with apt.  I really want absolutely nothing else except what is needed to install a package with apt - even the variant=minbase installs way too much unneeded stuff for my goal.

Comment: Seriously, `minbase` installs the minimum viable Debian system for the given release, 101 packages for Jessie. If you try to get away with anything less, you're asking for trouble down the road because any package can *rely* on *all* essential packages being installed, without depending on them.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. If you want to install Debian packages, use debootstrap and install Debian's package manager. Redoing the work that went into debootstrap will take you ages and will fail repeatedly as Debian evolves.

Comment: @StephenKitt what's the distinction between a dependency on a package and relying on a package? Surely if a package needs some other package then it either is or is not a dependency? How can packages need other packages without that relationship being defined anywhere?

Comment: "Dependency on a package" is declaring the package in the control file's "Depends" entry. "Relying on a package" is using anything that the package provides. Essential packages are assumed to be installed and can be relied upon with having a declared dependency.

Comment: The relevant sections of Policy are [3.5](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-dependencies) and [3.8](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s3.8). If you're unfamiliar with this then you probably shouldn't be working on a tool that tries to install a Debian system...

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm not trying to build a debian system, just trying to install packages. Your feedback has certainl;y been highly valuable and enlightening though thanks.

Comment: Nevertheless, you still need to satisfy the assumptions that Debian packages build upon, which includes the fact that all essential packages are always installed (and can operate all the time, even when they're not configured). And you're welcome!

Comment: ```sh
###
apt download --print-uris PACKAGE_NAME|cut -f 2 -d \' | grep \.deb

#E.g
apt download --print-uris deepin-terminal|cut -f 2 -d \' | grep \.deb

###
```

Answer (score 11):

Well, if you had apt available...

```
apt-get -y install --print-uris $PACKAGE | cut -f 2 -d \' | grep \.deb
```

It will actually give you all of the packages needed for whatever it is goign to install.

```
user@darkstar:~/ $ apt-get -y install --print-uris audacity | cut -f 2 -d \' | grep \.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsbsms/libsbsms10_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/serd/libserd-0-0_0.22.0~dfsg0-2_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sord/libsord-0-0_0.14.0~dfsg0-1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sratom/libsratom-0-0_0.4.6~dfsg0-1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/suil/libsuil-0-0_0.8.2~dfsg0-1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/audacity/audacity-data_2.1.2-1_all.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/flac/libflac++6v5_1.3.1-4_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libi/libid3tag/libid3tag0_0.15.1b-11_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lilv/liblilv-0-0_0.22.0~dfsg0-1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/portsmf/libportsmf0v5_0.1~svn20101010-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vamp-plugin-sdk/libvamp-hostsdk3v5_2.6~repack0-2_amd64.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/audacity/audacity_2.1.2-1_amd64.deb
```

Since you don't, look at http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64  and grab a copy of the Packages.gz file there.  Look through it, and you'll see The package name listed as

```
Package: audacity
```

A few lines after that, you'll see:

```
Filename: pool/main/a/audacity/audacity_2.0.6-2_amd64.deb
```

And there you go. Unfortunately, the line number isn't consistent.

Comment: See edit to explain why I cannot use apt.

Comment: Did you read the rest of my answer/reply? The part that comes after  "Since you dont..."

Comment: I couldn't get the first part of this answer to work. `apt-get -y install` assumes the package isn't already installed, and for packages that are already installed, `apt-get -y --reinstall install --print-uris $PACKAGE` always just prints "Reinstallation of $PACKAGE is not possible, it cannot be downloaded."

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have `apt` available, you'll be stuck basically reimplementing `apt`. It probably makes more sense to just get `apt`. But if you must...

Start the same way `apt` itself does: from a URL as specified in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, such as `http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/`. Don't forget the to take into account the additional entries you might have in that list for updates, security.debian.org, and possibly backports.

You need to evaluate the rules in `/etc/apt/preferences{,.d}` to know which source any particular package should come from and you need to do version number comparisons and to evaluate pinning rules.

Build a full URL from that:

```
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/<name>/<section>/binary-<architecture>/Packages.gz
```

That file contains the relative URLs to all of the individual packages.

You also need the following files in order to verify the hash of that file to check its integrity:

```
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg
```

...and the public key from `/etc/apt/trusted*` that lets you verify that. The `Release` file contains hashes for all the other files, which you should verify.

I'll have forgotten to take into account a bunch of other subtle rules about the format and layout of a Debian package repository.

As you can see, much better to **just use apt**.

Comment: See edit to explain why I cannot use apt.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to install and use `apt` .

To download the package run:

```
apt-get download libgcc1
```

To get the path to your `.deb` package , run:

```
apt-cache show libgcc1 | grep Filename
```

sample output:

```
Filename: pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/libgcc1_4.9.2-10_amd64.deb
```

Edit: To answer [@John](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332739/given-a-debian-package-name-how-do-i-get-a-url-to-the-latest-deb-url/332794?noredirect=1#comment1416136_332794).

If the package is already installed, you can use `grep-available` from `dctrl-tools` package:

```
sudo apt install dctrl-tools
```

Here is an example (search through the package `tar`):

```
grep-available -P tar -s Filename
```

Comment: See edit to explain why I cannot use apt.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `apt-cache show` does not ever seem to output a "Filename" property.

Comment: @John Welcome. See my edit.